# Trying to check multiple cells with .isBlank()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working on an Google Apps Script that will basically reset my spreadsheet at the end of the day.

```
if(ss.getRange('D2').isBlank()){ 
    ss.getRange('C2').moveTo(ss.getRange('D2')); 
  }
  if(ss.getRange('D3').isBlank()){
    ss.getRange('C3').moveTo(ss.getRange('D3'));
  }
  if(ss.getRange('D4').isBlank()){
    ss.getRange('C4').moveTo(ss.getRange('D4'));
  }
  if(ss.getRange('D5').isBlank()){
    ss.getRange('C5').moveTo(ss.getRange('D5'));
  }
```

That is what I am currently using but as you can probably tell this get's messy fast. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is way more efficient to work with arrays instead of individual values. In this way you only have to get and set the data once.**

In the following script adjust the sheet name and desired range. Range `C2:D10` assumes that column D is part of the if statement and C is the column you want to get the values if D is empty.

```
function myFunction() {

  const sheetName = 'Sheet1'; // define the name of the sheet
  const range = 'C2:D10'; // define the range

  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ss = sss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const data = ss.getRange(range).getValues();
  
  data.forEach((r,i)=>{
    data[i][1] = r[1] ==''? r[0] : r[1];
  })

  ss.getRange(range).setValues(data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try it with a forEach

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ['D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5'].forEach(r => {
    let rg = ss.getRange(r);
    if (rg.isBlank()) {
      ss.getRange(r).offset(0, -1).moveTo(rg)
    }
  });
}
```

While it is true there are certainly more efficient ways of doing this.  I felt that the ui was improved because all you have to do is tack a few more ranges on to the array and they need not be contiguous.  Of course if difference range and difference methodologies then you would have to modify the script.